# Check if user seeks in Youtube API?

Tags: javascript, events, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I'm working with the youtube-iframe-api and so far it's been pretty great! however i have ran into one problem, I'm not sure how to go about checking if the player seeks to a part of the video?

they have a method called seekTo() but that only lets you change where your seeking, it does not check. I looked into all the state changes, but non of them check to see if the user skips to a later part of the video, or if they go back to an earlier part.

Does anyone have any experience with this? so far the only state changes i see on the API are:

```
YT.PlayerState.ENDED
YT.PlayerState.PLAYING
YT.PlayerState.PAUSED
YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING
YT.PlayerState.CUED
```